# Dynamic annotion in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django queryset being created for a graph like the following:

```
obj = Allotment.objects
    .all()
    .values('dispatch_date')
    .annotate(transaction_no=Count('transaction_no'))
    .values('dispatch_date', 'transaction_no')
```

Now I am trying to pass all these values dynamically so I tried this :

```
    data = request.data.copy()
    x_model = data['x_model']
    y_model = data['y_model']
    obj = Allotment.objects
        .all()
        .values('{}'.format(x_model))
        .annotate(transaction_no=Count('{}'.format(y_model)))
        .values('{}'.format(x_model), '{}'.format(y_model))
```

where I just replaced the string values and it gives me the following error:

> The annotation 'transaction_no' conflicts with a field on the model.

How do I dynamically change the field in annotate function? and apply aggregators such as
`Sum`, `Count`, etc given that the aggregators are passed through the API as well

Comment: Your model has a field named "transaction_no", you can't have an annotation with the same name, your first queryset should fail with the same error. Can you share the model?

Comment: @IainShelvington Okay.. got it! But how can I pass the aggregators dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error

> The annotation 'transaction_no' conflicts with a field on the model.

because you have already declared a field **transaction_no** in your model and you cannot use this parameter inside the annotation on the **Queryset** concerning this model

You can dynamically pass what you expect in annotate function using the unpacking feature of python.
from your snippets, it could be something like this

```
annotate_dict = {
    "count_x_model":Count("x_model"),
    "count_y_model":Count("y_model")
}
second_values = ["x_model", "y_model"]

obj = Allotment.objects
        .all()
        .values('{}'.format(x_model))
        .annotate(**annotate_dict)
        .values(*second_values)
```

You can read about this from here [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)